# Create communication site in private group (MS Teams team)

Tags: team-sites, microsoft-teams, communication-site

I want to create a communication site within the private group of a Teams team.
When I create a new site it only allows me to create team sites, not communication sites.

Do I have to create a totally new site (with URL etc.) and link to it in Teams or what else can I do?
Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a new site. Communication sites are not backed by a Microsoft 365 Group thus cannot host a Microsoft Team. What you can do is create the Comm site and then use the webpage tab in Teams to allow users to navigate to it within the Teams client.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor. I was afraid that I had to do that. I wanted to avoid creating unnessesary URLs but thats the way it works. :)